# How do I pipe ls to grep, and delete the files filtered by grep?

Tags: grep, pipe, ls, rm

I wanted to delete some package in my home file, but the filename was too long (`google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb`). So, I decided to use the command `ls|grep chrome|rm` to pipe the files to grep to filter out the chrome file, and then remove it. It didn't work, so I would like to see how I can do this.

Comment: `rm -i *chrome*.deb`

Comment: Generally speaking I dislike when people post "don't do that" answers, but this is one of the best examples of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I've ever seen. Your real question is "how do I quickly delete a file with a long filename, without typing the whole thing out", and there are lots of good ways that don't involve grepping the output from `ls`

Comment: Just use `find` - `find . -name "*chrome*" -delete`.

Comment: i like saying popular stuff!

Comment: Hello there, do you have a moment to talk about our lord and saviour? Tab-autocomplete? Hmm... no you say? Have you heard of `xargs`?

Comment: Obligatory links: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: The simple way is to type "google-chrome" and hit the tab key.

Comment: My two cents as a StackExchange user: in the future, ask your question in a more generic way while providing details about what you have tried. "How do I delete any files in a folder with a certain string in the filename?" might have been a better way to phrase it. Then you could simply add, as an aside, that you tried piping `ls` through `grep` to `rm` but couldn't get it to work. That way you'll get one or two good answers about the "correct" or "easiest" way to accomplish your task rather than forcing someone to give you a good answer about an inefficient solution.

Comment: @MichealJohnson This really isn't the best way to do it, especially if you are not using a terminal emulator.

Comment: @SpecialBomb He said "the filename was too long". I assume from the length of the filename that he doesn't mean "the filename was too long for the system to process" but rather "the filename was too long for me to type" so he's using the command line interactively and is trying to shortcut the typing of long filenames. To answer the question, no, the tab key isn't always a replacement for "pipe `ls` to `grep` and delete the files filtered by `grep`", but this is a classic example of [asking the wrong question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This almost made me wince.

1. You might want to stop pointing that [shotgun](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) at your foot. Basically any kind of parsing of `ls` is going to be more [complicated and error-prone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) than established methods like [`find [...] -exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247933/3645) or [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
2. Unless someone installed a troll distro for you, your shell has <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion. Just type `rm google` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If it doesn't complete immediately, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to see a list of matching files. Type more characters of the filename to narrow it down until it does complete, then run the command.
3. [Pipes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes) != [parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters). Standard input is a *binary data stream* which can be fed to a command asynchronously. Parameters are space separated strings which are passed once and only once to a command when running it. These are very rarely interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed like a n00b question. I knew it was okay to use generally, as the package stated was the only package with "chrome" stated in it. Therefore, using grep would filter out only one file. I am pretty new to linux, and I have already done plenty of bash scripts, but I don't know everything yet :P. Harsh, dude.

Comment: Didn't mean to be harsh, but the shell is a harsh and unforgiving environment, hidden behind a kinda user friendly surface. Doing things *safely* is difficult enough, never mind *securely* or even *correctly*.

Comment: @SpecialBomb This is the only correct answer. Explaining how to correctly aim said shotgun to cleanly cut off one's foot, as the other answers do, is certainly not the way to go. Be especially careful of blindly executing `rm` - it's probably the single more common way to fry your distro.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Heh, I've definitely already fried Ubuntu twice installing AMD graphics card drivers. I already asked a question about that though. AMD has been horrible, so I asked if there were any common fixes or better methods of gaming with Linux on an AMD card.

Comment: What would be best for a Makefile task that removes all files starting with 'foo' and ending with 'bar'? I had in mind `ls | grep "foo*bar" | rm`

Comment: I think I found the answer from the link: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*chrome*' -delete` To the uninitiated, this doesn't look that different, with the exception that it has the maxdepth parameter (which is obviously a great safety feature). Is there anything else to be aware of?

Comment: @stevec If you want clarity around how `find` works I would recommend `man find` or asking another question here. "anything else to be aware of" is a theme big enough for a book.

Comment: It bugs me that this is the accepted answer, but it isn't _the_ answer. It's advice for a path to the answer... and all that was needed as icing on the cake was the actual way to use find properly. Voting up the other answer that provided that instead.

Answer (score 59):

You had the right idea, just missed some details. Since you're dealing with a list coming to STDIN and `rm` expects parameters, you need to use `xargs`.

Thus:

```
ls | grep chrome | xargs rm
```

Should give you what you want.

Note that if you want to delete everything other than the `chrome` file, you can simply add `-v` to the `grep` statement.

Note that, per the other answers to this question, this is probably a bad way of accomplishing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: With `-v`, wouldn't this delete everything _except_ for files that match `chrome`? I don't think that's what the OP wants...

Comment: Looking again, you're correct. The OP wants to "filter out the chrome file", but then wants to remove it.

Comment: This seems needlessly complex, compared to a simple "rm -i *chrome*"

Comment: What specifically does 'xargs' do?

Comment: `xargs` takes STDIN and turns it into command line parameters for the specified command given to it.

Comment: That may be an oversimplification of what `xargs` does, admittedly, but it is an answer I feel is sufficient within the context of this question.

Comment: The accepted answer works, but see the answer below which explains why it's a bad idea.  (Posting this comment here only for the sake of those who stop as soon as they see an "accepted" checkmark.)

Comment: This, the accepted answer "works" _only if there are no "weird" filenames_ in the `ls` output. Filenames with spaces will wreck this. This is also _dangerous_ if someone can construct a filename with special sauce in the directory where you run this.  As more than one person has already pointed out, [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!

Answer (score 40):

You can also use the find command with a wildcard:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*chrome*' -delete
```

Note that the "-maxdepth" argument ensures that find only works in the current directory, and doesn't recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Suggestions for improvements: (a) use `-iname` for case-insensitive filenames (b) pipe to `xargs` using `-print0` flag for `find` and `-0` flag for `xargs`. The use of `xargs` allows you to do things like "interactive" (confirm delete `foo`?) deletes.

Comment: No need to pipe to xargs if you use -exec option: `find . -name '*chrome*' -exec rm -i {} +`

Comment: Won't this also delete recursively into subdirectories? You may need to specify `maxdepth` to be 1.

Answer (score 16):

**Never parse the output of ls**
My suggestion is to **avoid to parse the output of ls** <sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/66388)]</sup>, even more if in conjunction with the `del` command. This for many reasons  mainly related to unexpected and not usual characters allowed in the file name.

Even when you should expect that the filenames belonging to Linux packages will *"behave well"*, this problem can nonetheless appears if other files are present in the same directory but you didn't know or notice.

It's better to use `find`, the tab expansion (start to write the name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>), the *file name expansion* <sup>[[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08)]</sup> as `*MyKey*`...

---

**A fast solution**
Since you want to select all the packages (that finish with `.deb`) with *"google"* inside you can build your request with the wildcard `*`  `*google*.deb` and do a simple

```
rm -i *google*.deb
```

that will select each *filename* with *"google"* in the middle that will finish for `.deb` present in the current directory. The option `-i` (interactive) will prompt for the confirmation, a good habit when you delete files with the parameter expansion.

---

**A solution close to the philosophy of your attempt**
If your purpose is to build your commandline piece after piece, so you have done `ls`, after `ls | grep google`, and **only after you checked your output** you can execute it in a subshell `$(...)` with

```
rm -i $(ls | grep google)
```

A faster and **more dangerous way** <sup>[[3](https://superuser.com/a/776767/257269)]</sup>, is to use `!!`

```
ls | grep google
rm -i $(!!)
```

that will execute **the last command finished in your history**. You can protect yourself from the fact that you have no visual control of the line that you are going to execute if you have enabled in advance the shell options `histverify` with `shopt -s histverify`.

Answer (score 5):

```
touch 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
find . -name \[0-9] -ok rm {} \;
```

---

```
< rm ... ./0 > ? y
< rm ... ./9 > ? y
< rm ... ./8 > ? y
< rm ... ./7 > ? y
< rm ... ./6 > ? y
< rm ... ./5 > ? y
< rm ... ./4 > ? y
< rm ... ./3 > ? y
< rm ... ./2 > ? y
< rm ... ./1 > ? y
^C
```

...use `-name '*c*.deb'` or some other pattern as suits you instead.

Answer (score 3):

`rm` doesn't accept input from `stdin`.  You'll need to do something like `ls google-chrome* | xargs rm`