# What is the best way to delete automatically generated files from a folder, knowing that the folder may include manually created files not to delete?

Tags: find, delete

This seemed great:  `find . ! -name *custom.conf -delete`

But it does not work if I don't have any custom.conf :(

I am thinking about:

- split into 2 folders
- use a regex in the find command

disclaimer: this is my first question here, I thought it could have been better to add a comment to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247973/247207 but I don't have the required reputation to post a comment

Comment: Escape the `*`: `\*custom.conf` or quote it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer 's right! find . ! -name "*custom.conf" -f -delete this should just work, or your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the filename globbing pattern on the command line will be expanded by the shell (if it matches any names in the current directory) before the utility is invoked.

This means that the actual command being executed may be something like

```
find . ! -name thing1-custom.conf thing2-custom.conf thing3-custom.conf -delete
```

You can see this if you enable tracing with `set -x` on the command line before invoking the command.  Use `set +x` to later turn off tracing.

Your command also ought to have given you one of the error messages `unknown option` or `paths must precede expression` depending on your implementation of the `find` utility.

The correct thing to do here is to quote the pattern from the shell, as Michael Homer pointed out in comments (he says to escape the `*`, but quoting the whole pattern is IMHO nicer looking and has the same effect):

```
find . ! -name '*custom.conf' -delete
```

This way, the pattern is handed over to `find` as is, and the utility will do its own matching against all the names in the current directory.

I would also add `-type f` to that so that we're sure we'll only act on regular files:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*custom.conf' -delete
```